# How to pass object as scope to eval?

Tags: javascript

I've a javascript object like the following:

```
var myobj = {
    'a': 10, 'b': 20
}
```

I've a condition stored in a string like the followin:

```
var c = 'a==10';
```

I want to evaluate whether the condition in c is true or false. The variables referred in the condition string e.g. `a` is a member of `myobj`.

I've tried the following but it didn't help.

```
eval.call(myobj, 'a==10');
```

Comment: That is not "context". You want a property to become a variable. That is a different concept.

Comment: @trincot rephrased the question

Comment: @Nayan do you want to check if `a` is `10`? `c = (myobj.a == 10)`

Comment: Are your expressions arbitrary JavaScript? If it's some reasonable subset, implementing a way to parse these expressions and execute them would be a better solution than using `eval`. Also, you should check whether you want to use strict mode or not, as the behavior of `eval` changes depending on that. I don't see an easy way to use `eval` to achieve what you want, as it would probably end up depending on the global object and clobbering it. Consider someone wanting to use something from it (say `Math.abs()`). Your context could have matching properties. What should happen in such case?

Comment: @Pilan Unfortunately the conditions comes from another source and I can't change them.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 indeed. This is either a trivial one-liner or the question is too broad. No in-between.

Comment: @Nayan ok got it, gimme a sec :)

Comment: You could consider using a `with` statement. It's considered harmful, but it would look something like `with (myobj) eval(c)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really question why you want to use dynamic JS content like that. If the value for `c` is provided by users then you need to sanitise that input before using it in `eval`. There are almost always better alternatives.

Therefore the solution I now propose is really enforcing a bad practice -- and not available in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

```
var res = eval('with (myobj) ' + c);
```

Or, depending how you get the info about `myobj`, this may be easier/more difficult:

```
with (myobj) var res = eval(c);
```

So now let's look at some safer ways. Instead of working with such values of `c`, build a structure of expressions that you allow. For instance:

```
var c = { prop: "a", operation: "equal", constant: 10 };
```

... and then do something like this:

```
var operations = {
    equal(a, b) => a == b,
    // define other operations here ...
};

function test(obj, c) {
    return operations[c.operation](obj[c.prop], c.constant);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `with` statements are forbidden in strict mode code.

Comment: @JordanRunning, indeed, an important remark. Added.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I'm trying to parse the conditions and evaluate them. Right now it's easy as there are only some fixed conditions. But parsing and evaluating will become a tough task when the conditions will be complex. In python `eval` takes a scope object and I expected it in JS too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt at a super hacky solution to this problem using [the `Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) (written in ES2015):

```js
const context = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
};

const expression = 'a==10';

const getAllMatches = (pattern, string) =>
      // make sure string is a String, and make sure pattern has the /g flag
      String(string).match(new RegExp(pattern, 'g'));

// this pattern is far from robust
const variablePattern = /[a-zA-Z$_][0-9a-zA-Z$_]*/;

const evalWithContext = (context, expression) => {
  const variables = getAllMatches(variablePattern, expression);

  // function and arguments are keywords, so I use abbreviated names
  const func = new Function(...variables, `return (${expression})`);

  const args = variables.map((arg) => (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(context, arg)
                                       ? context[arg]
                                       : undefined));

  return func(...args);
};

console.log(evalWithContext(context, expression));
```

Answer (score -1):

So dirty :D

```js
var myobj = {
    'a': 10,
    'b': 20
}

var c = 'a==10';

var res = (function() {
  return eval('this.' + c + ';');
}).apply(myobj);

console.log(res);

// or as onliner

var res2 = ((o) => eval('o.' + c)).call(null, myobj);
console.log(res2);
```